# Fazer loop a um select com vários Ids

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Pretendo fazer uma consulta à base de dados com o filtor de vários Ids, para retornar as linhas correspondentes. Estou a tentar desta forma:

Primeiro envio os ids através do js:

```
function update_estado()
{   
    var pedpront = [];
      $.each($("input[name='updpront']:checked"), function(){            
          pedpront.push($(this).val());
          
      });

    var dadosajax = {
        'Id[]' : pedpront ,
        'Fornecedor' : $("#Fornecedor3").val(),
        'Estado' : $("#Estado1").val(),
        'Observacao' : $("#Observacao").val()
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'pedencom.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){
          $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
          swal("Erro!", "Tente novamente. Caso persista o erro, contatar Administrador!", "error");
        },
        success: function(result2)
        {
        $('.limp9')[0].reset();
      }
    });
}
```

Envia os Ids separados desta forma:

```
Id[]:23
Id[]:24
```

Depois no php estou a tentar fazer o `loop` desta forma:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($Id);$i++)
{

if($Id[$i]!="")
{
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT dados.Encomendas.Id_Enc, dados.Encomendas.Orcamento, NotaEnco, dados.Encomendas.Fornecedor AS IdForn, 

dados.NovoForn.Fornecedor, Ref, Designacao, Quantidade, Observacao

FROM dados.Encomendas LEFT OUTER JOIN dados.Orcamento ON dados.Orcamento.Id = dados.Encomendas.Id_Enc

LEFT OUTER JOIN dados.NovoForn ON dados.NovoForn.Id = dados.Encomendas.Fornecedor

LEFT OUTER JOIN dados.EncEmail ON dados.EncEmail.IdEnc = dados.Encomendas.Id_Enc WHERE dados.Encomendas.Id_Enc IN (:Id)

ORDER BY dados.NovoForn.Fornecedor ASC");

    $stmt1->bindValue(':Id', $Id[$i], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt1->execute();
}
}

while($row1=$stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){       
        $Orcamento = $row1["Orcamento"];
        $Ref1 = $row1["Ref"];
        $Designacao1 = $row1["Designacao"];
        $Quantidade1 = $row1["Quantidade"];
}
```

Mas desta forma só retorna uma linha, mesmo que envie mais de um Id pela url. Pretendia que por exemplo se enviasse 3 ids, retornasse as 3 linhas correspondentes aos 3 ids.

Comment: ao invés de fazer esse loop pq você não dá um implode nos ids e passa eles no IN (ids)

Comment: @Lucas Miranda Também já tentei fazer o implode e não funcionou. Fiz assim `ids = implode(" ,", $Id)` e depois coloquei `WHERE dados.Encomendas.Id_Enc IN (:ids)` e não funcionou. O `Ids` ficava nulo, mas mantive o `for($i=0;$i<count($Id);$i++){`. Pode colocar um exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente fazer um loop para concatenar os IDs e depois dar bind na query. Assim com o array de `$Id` sendo `[0] => 23, [1] => 24` cria-se um `foreach`:

```
$ids = '';
foreach($id as $dados)
{
  $ids .= "{$dados}, ";
}
```

Porem ao final do `foreach` a variável `$ids` teria o valor: `"23, 24, "` para resolver isso temos que retirar os últimos dois caracteres da string, então usamos substr:

```
$ids = substr($ids, 0,-2);
```

E o valor de `$ids` ficaria `"23, 24"` com isso podemos dar bind `$stmt1->bindValue(':Id', $ids);`

Por fim, o código ficaria:

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT dados.Encomendas.Id_Enc, dados.Encomendas.Orcamento, NotaEnco, dados.Encomendas.Fornecedor AS IdForn, 

dados.NovoForn.Fornecedor, Ref, Designacao, Quantidade, Observacao

FROM dados.Encomendas LEFT OUTER JOIN dados.Orcamento ON dados.Orcamento.Id = dados.Encomendas.Id_Enc

LEFT OUTER JOIN dados.NovoForn ON dados.NovoForn.Id = dados.Encomendas.Fornecedor

LEFT OUTER JOIN dados.EncEmail ON dados.EncEmail.IdEnc = dados.Encomendas.Id_Enc WHERE dados.Encomendas.Id_Enc IN (:Id)

ORDER BY dados.NovoForn.Fornecedor ASC");

$stmt1->bindValue(':Id', $ids);
$stmt1->execute();
$row1 = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Lembre-se que somente se usa `fetch()` para retornar uma unica linha para seu caso seriam três, então usa-se o `fetchAll()`, com isso `$row1` sera um array.

Recomendo que de um `var_dump($row1)` para ver como ficara o retorno antes de usar.

Comment: Funcionou, mas tive de retirar esta linha `$stmt1->bindValue(':Id', $ids);` e colocar a variável direta na consulta desta forma ` WHERE dados.Encomendas.Id_Enc IN ($ids)'. Só assim retornou as linhas todas de acordo com os ids que envio no array.

Comment: Não recomendo que faça isso, a função bindValues é usada para prevenir injeção SQL. Recomendo fortemente sempre evitar colocar variáveis diretamente na query, principalmente se for algum input de usuário, tome cuidado.

Comment: sim em nenhum caso uso variáveis diretamente na query, mas neste caso continuo sem conseguir colocar a funcionar com `bindValue` mesmo a alternativa que colocou que até eliminou. Não consigo entender a razão/motivo de só funcionar se colocar a variável direta na query